# How to make separate requests for each item of Recyclerview?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, rx-java2

I have a RecyclerView and the list of data it represent. I fetch data from Server/DB which contains unique Id, based on this item Id I want to make request to Server/DB and want to display it on RecyclerView.

I'm making separate request and I want to request as much items as it's visible on screen.

I have already defined 10 items which I receive from server and show them but for every item I need to do additional request  for more detail and show on the same screen

In onBindViewHolder for each item to show subtitles of each item I'm making additional request

```
  viewModel.loadSubtitles(item.getId())
      .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
      .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
      .subscribe({item->
          holder.binding.textView.setText(item.getSubTitle());
        }
      });
```

But When I'm scrolling it every time make request to DB/Services
I want to have only once for each item.

Comment: Not clear need more specification

Comment: use ThreadPoolExecutor for every request and call execute in onBindView of RecyclerViewAdapter ,Read on [ThreadPoolExecutor](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html)

Comment: @Sanjay Majoka I have updated my question

Comment: Did you get a good solution?I am looking for the solution of same.if u got please update.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Pull to Refresh/SwipeRefreshLayout for RecyclerView. Here is the code sample link.

http://android-er.blogspot.com/2016/05/swiperefreshlayout-work-with.html

Answer (score 0):

You mean you want to show detail information for each item onclick on that item right?

If I'm true, give item's the whole view an id and set onclick listener to that view in onBindViewHolder. You should show detail information in another activity so that you can change activity with Intent and put Key value to show onclicked item information.

Comment: No I don't want to navigate to another activity or fragment, I need to show on the same screen for each item, my problem how can I organize that loading from server and displaying that it could not mix the items and display the info not on right items